# Is there a way to retrieve which service the FPFile objects are from in the Filepicker.io JS API?

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

Title should say it all. I'm curious if there is a way to retrieve or access which service (e.g. Facebook, Instagram, etc.) the FPFile object is from in the response received after a successful pick or pickMultiple call within the Javascript API? Our app would love to have access to that information.

Comment: Filepicker.io imports files from various services and locations. Once done Filepicker returns an FPFile object containing the following properties: url, filename, mimetype, size, key, isWriteable. Judging by the documentation and API examples, there currently is no way to get the 'used service' for a given FPFile.

Comment: Right, I'm hoping someone from Filepicker will respond with more information about future plans or a different method to access this data.

Comment: Figured as much, which is why I added my response as comment instead of an answer.